# How to increase the width of this blog? (Width of the main body and widget)

Tags: html, css, web, width, blogger

This is the link to the blog https://www.glamiva.com/2021/09/its-been-while.html

Issue:

1. I want the page size to occupied 100% of the screen instead of it is currently now. Can you show the code section that I need to edit?

I include the below image to make it easier to understand:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is :

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Set the same but with `width: auto;` or 100% to overwrite the basic rule

Comment: Hi. I found the code segment. Now it works. Thanks a lot! ^^

Comment: Hi again @MaxiGui , do u have the time to check on my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69548642/17138604) ? I still don't have the solution for that problem. 
Thank your very much for your previous help!

Answer (score 0):

What technology do you used ?

You could change the container size of your web to 100%.
[reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp)
For example :

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Hi. It works ^^ Thanks for the solution and the link given! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi again @surya , do u have the time to check on my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69548642/17138604) ? I still don't have the solution for that problem. Thank your very much for your previous help!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Btw you can tell stackoverflow if my answer is accepted by clicking the button accepted answer on the left side. I already answer your question.